# Splitting a string based on delimiter using SQL

Tags: sql, db2, ibm-midrange

I have a "flat file" with structure as below:

```
machineCode,Key,Ip_Name_No,Share_Percent,Account_Name,Account_No                       
"ygh048GT",4767,534293748,"100.00","cderfgdsc Publishing International Ltd","160102040"  
"xcd064HW",6380,65424090,"100.00","dascdfrgh snm skion","00090382478"                    
"000065AN",6402,65424090,"100.00","xcdertn,john sean","00090382478"                    
.....
```

The first row are the column headings. As can be seen, the fields are separated by a comma.
The requirement is to split the single string into separate fields.

This could be done by excel and then uploaded to a DB table using the data to columns option with comma as delimiter but the Account_Name field can contain commas within the values itself.

So, I came up with the below SQL. Question is, does this look correct ? Also, there must be some easier way to do this, any suggestions ?

```
WITH POS AS (
select 
LOCATE_IN_STRING ( DATA , ',' , 2 )  - 1 AS TUNECODE_END ,
LOCATE_IN_STRING (DATA, ',' ,  LOCATE_IN_STRING ( DATA , ',' , 2 ) + 1)  - 1 AS WORKKEY_END,
LOCATE_IN_STRING( DATA , ','  ,   (LOCATE_IN_STRING (DATA, ',' ,  LOCATE_IN_STRING ( DATA , ',' , 2 ) + 1) + 1) ) - 1 AS IPNN_END,
LOCATE_IN_STRING( DATA , ','  , (LOCATE_IN_STRING( DATA , ','  ,   (LOCATE_IN_STRING (DATA, ',' ,  LOCATE_IN_STRING ( DATA , ',' , 2 ) + 1) + 1) )  + 1) ) - 1 AS PERC_END,

CASE WHEN
 SUBSTR ( DATA , 
(
LOCATE_IN_STRING ( DATA , ',' , 
(LOCATE_IN_STRING( DATA , ','  , (LOCATE_IN_STRING( DATA , ','  ,   (LOCATE_IN_STRING (DATA, ',' ,  LOCATE_IN_STRING ( DATA , ',' , 2 ) + 1) + 1) )  + 1) ) + 1 ) ) + 1),
1) <> '"' 
THEN
LOCATE_IN_STRING ( DATA , ',' ,  
(LOCATE_IN_STRING ( DATA , ',' , 
(LOCATE_IN_STRING( DATA , ','  , (LOCATE_IN_STRING( DATA , ','  ,   (LOCATE_IN_STRING (DATA, ',' ,  LOCATE_IN_STRING ( DATA , ',' , 2 ) + 1) + 1) )  + 1) ) + 1 ) ) + 1)) - 1 

ELSE

LOCATE_IN_STRING ( DATA , ',' , 
(LOCATE_IN_STRING( DATA , ','  , (LOCATE_IN_STRING( DATA , ','  ,   (LOCATE_IN_STRING (DATA, ',' ,  LOCATE_IN_STRING ( DATA , ',' , 2 ) + 1) + 1) )  + 1) ) + 1 ) ) - 1

END AS ACNAME_END,
RRN(P) ROWN

FROM PLDWRK P 

) SELECT 

CAST ( SUBSTR( DATA , 1, TUNECODE_END ) AS CHAR(25))AS MACHINECODE ,
CAST ( SUBSTR( DATA , TUNECODE_END + 2 ,  WORKKEY_END - (TUNECODE_END + 1)  ) AS DEC(12,0))  AS KEY,
CAST(SUBSTR( DATA , WORKKEY_END + 2,  IPNN_END - (WORKKEY_END + 1) ) AS DEC(12, 0 )) AS IP_NN,
CAST (SUBSTR( DATA, IPNN_END + 2, PERC_END - (IPNN_END + 1)) AS CHAR(8))AS PERCENTAGE,
CAST (SUBSTR( DATA, PERC_END + 2, ACNAME_END - (PERC_END + 1)) AS CHAR(100)) AS ACCOUNT_NAME,
CAST (SUBSTR( DATA, ACNAME_END + 2 ) AS CHAR(30)) as ACCOUNT_NUMBER

 FROM PLDWRK P JOIN POS ON ROWN = RRN(P)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lots of things are easier than raw SQL...

- Why not simply use [Copy From Import File (CPYFRMIMPF)](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/i/7.4?topic=ssw_ibm_i_74/cl/cpyfrmimpf.html) that's what it's designed for.
  `CPYFRMIMPF FROMSTMF('/inbound/somedata.csv') TOFILE(MYLIB/MYTABLE) MBROPT(*REPLACE) RCDDLM(*CRLF) DTAFMT(*DLM) STRDLM(*DBLQUOTE) RMVCOLNAM(*YES)`
  You'll have to transfer the stream data into the IFS (where it really belongs) instead of a DB table.
- IBM's Access Client Solutions (ACS) includes data transfer functionality that can understand .CSV files.  This can be automated and can in fact run on either a PC or the IBM i itself.
- Another great option would be an RPG program, back in 2008 Scott Klement wrote a [CSV parser in RPG](https://www.scottklement.com/csv/).  He's since enhanced it to make it easier to use by taking advantage of RPG's `DATA-INTO` op-code.
- Lastly it's 2023...node.js, PHP, Python are all available on the IBM i and all of them have libraries/packages to handle CSV and write to a DB table.

Comment: Could you please confirm if the CPYFRMIMPF command as above would work as required? As can be seen in my sample data, not all fields are string delimited. The first field is, but not the second field. How can this be handled ?

Comment: Define the second field as a numeric field in your table.

Comment: Second and third fields, to be precise. @Theju112: The delimiter is a comma. The enclosing quotes designate a field as "string", to make sure that the parsing application can successfully differ between the delimiter itself, and the possible occurrence of the delimiter within a string.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! The reason why CPYFRMIMPF didn't really cross my mind was because the flat file is actually as a member of a PF. So, I was trying to access it through an alias as I always had the thought that *IMPF commands were IFS RELATED. But as I have found out now, these commands serve my purpose! CPYFRMIMPF FROMFILE(THEPAV/IACEARTHP A000767967) TOFILE(THEPAV/AFILE) MBROPT(*REPLACE) RCDDLM(*CRLF)  and                                    
CPYTOIMPF FROMFILE(THEPAV/AFILE) TOSTMF('/HOME/THEPAV/A.CSV') MBROPT(*REPLACE) RCDDLM(*CRLF) RMVBLANK(*BOTH)

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't work properly for the last row, since one token contains `,` inside...

```
select 
  t.str
, regexp_substr (t.str, '[^,]+', 1, 1) as tok1
, regexp_substr (t.str, '[^,]+', 1, 2) as tok2
---, ...
, regexp_substr (t.str, '[^,]+', 1, 6) as tok6
from
(
values
  (1, 'machineCode,Key,Ip_Name_No,Share_Percent,Account_Name,Account_No')
, (2, '"ygh048GT",4767,534293748,"100.00","cderfgdsc Publishing International Ltd","160102040"')
, (3, '"xcd064HW",6380,65424090,"100.00","dascdfrgh snm skion","00090382478"')
, (4, '"000065AN",6402,65424090,"100.00","xcdertn,john sean","00090382478"')
) t (id, str)
order by t.id
```

| STR | TOK1 | TOK2 | TOK6 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| machineCode,Key,Ip_Name_No,Share_Percent,Account_Name,Account_No | machineCode | Key | Account_No |
| "ygh048GT",4767,534293748,"100.00","cderfgdsc Publishing International Ltd","160102040" | "ygh048GT" | 4767 | "160102040" |
| "xcd064HW",6380,65424090,"100.00","dascdfrgh snm skion","00090382478" | "xcd064HW" | 6380 | "00090382478" |
| "000065AN",6402,65424090,"100.00","xcdertn,john sean","00090382478" | "000065AN" | 6402 | john sean" |

Comment: works for me! just tested

Comment: Already did it long back ??